# Generate Max Value Expression

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, arithmetic

How to insert * AND + OPERATORS between a given set of integers so that the expression evaluates to the max possible value

if Set is [3,4,5,6,-2] it should give 3*4*5*6+-2 and also note that * gets precedence over + while evaluating

Saw this in a blog, but could not come up with an answer other than doing a brute force exhaustive search

Transferred from Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't have enough for a proper answer, but at the very least, it looks like the only cases that require thought ought to be when you're dealing with integers that are less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Does the order of the integers matter?

Comment: yes order matters, sorry i missed it

Comment: what abt 1,1,1 ?

Comment: Sounds of comment being deleted...

Comment: @CalvinLin OP mentioned that the members of the set are integers.

Comment: Ah missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Can numbers repeat, e.g., with more than one zero in the sequence?

Comment: numbers can be repeated